# How can I find the co-ordinates where the user wearing a VR Headset is looking at in a 360 video playing insider Unity Skybox?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, skybox

I am trying to find the gaze co-ordinates of a user wearing a HTC Vive with integrated Tobii Eyetracker. The user is viewing a 360-degree video playing inside a Unity Skybox. I am using the Tobii Pro SDK.

I have used the VREyeTracker Prefab of Tobii and am getting parameters and values in the XML file (more details below in results). How is Unity Data different from Raw Data? Since I am not able to find any document with relevant description, I am not sure if the results obtained in the XML contain the information I am looking for.

Unity Data:

```
GazeDirection Value="(-0.05267334, 0.01541138, 0.99848940)" Valid="True" />
<GazeOrigin Value="(-0.03057870, 0.00478235, -0.04329382)" Valid="True" />
<PupilDiameter Value="0.00168019" Valid="True" />
<GazeRayWorld Origin="(-0.40116220, 1.04663500, -0.38193990)" Direction="(0.24876200, 0.05519217, 0.96699090)" Valid="True" />
```

Raw Data:

```
<GazeDirection UnitVector="(0.05267334, 0.01541138, 0.99848940)" Validity="Valid" />
<GazeOrigin PositionInHMDCoordinates="(30.57870000, 4.78234900, -43.29382000)" Validity="Valid" />
<Pupil PupilDiameter="1.68019100" Validity="Valid" />
PupilPosition PositionInTrackingArea="(0.55140850, 0.63337760)" Validity="Valid" />
```

Comment: `How is Unity Data different from Raw Data?` -> you are getting different tags ... the "gaze" direction is the same for both (except the sign of X) .. is this maybe the head orientation? Also the pupil diameter and GazeOrigin seem to use different scales .. probably Unity measures in meter while Pupil raw measures in millimeters

Comment: Thanks @derHugo for your inputs. You are quite right with the Unity and Tobii measurement units (http://developer.tobiipro.com/unity/unity-getting-started.html#TipsAndHints). I am trying to understand which of these can I use to calculate 1) Head Position and 2) screen co-ordinates where the user is looking at in a Unity Skybox running a 360-degree video.

Comment: I forgot to write about this part of the output:                                                   
<Pose Position="(-0.26140150, 0.93376760, 0.11820720)" Rotation="(0.00575974, 0.11311300, -0.00657768, 0.99354370)" Valid="True" />

Comment: The question is: do you get the fixation (gaze) position/direction in absolute world coordinates or relative to the head position and orientation? (I know e.g. the MagicLeap provides everything in absolute world coordinates regardless of the head transforms). To 1) you usually don't have to calculate the head position/orientation .. the API of the HTC Vive should already provide them to Unity -> Camera position.

Comment: Thanks @derHugo. How would one obtain them relative to head position and orientation?

Comment: I'm currently loading the SDK .. could you add the code you used to optain these XML strings to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare both data sets you can quite easily see the following relations:

- Unity Data

  ```
  <GazeDirection Value="(-0.05267334, 0.01541138, 0.99848940)" Valid="True" />
  ```

  is related to

  Raw Data

  ```
  <GazeDirection UnitVector="(0.05267334, 0.01541138, 0.99848940)" Validity="Valid" />
  ```

  but with inverted X axis
- Unity Data

  ```
  <GazeOrigin Value="(-0.03057870, 0.00478235, -0.04329382)" Valid="True" />
  ```

  is ralted to

  Raw Data

  ```
  <GazeOrigin PositionInHMDCoordinates="(30.57870000, 4.78234900, -43.29382000)" Validity="Valid" />
  ```

  but with inverted X axis and a factor 1000 (Unity measures in meters, tobii in millimeters). This name sounds like this is the origin of the gaze ray relative to the head/hmd device -> a bit (3cm) left, a bit above (1.5cm) the center of the hmd and 4cm behind the device.
- Unity Data

  ```
  <PupilDiameter Value="0.00168019" Valid="True" />
  ```

  is related to

  Raw Data

  ```
  <Pupil PupilDiameter="1.68019100" Validity="Valid" />
  ```

  again with the factor 1000

Finally

Unity Data

```
<GazeRayWorld Origin="(-0.40116220, 1.04663500, -0.38193990)" Direction="(0.24876200, 0.05519217, 0.96699090)" Valid="True" />
```

sounds like it is related to the `GazeOrigin` but this time not relative to the HDM but in world coordinates where Direction is the fixation vector also in world space. Meaning in world coordinates you are looking 25cm to the left, 6cm up and 1meter in front of the position `(-0.40116220, 1.04663500, -0.38193990)` (sounds like you were sitting or are very small ;) ) in world space.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Many Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to understand the location of the object the user is looking at in terms of azimuth and elevation with the camera position at say (0.0.0) i.e the centre of the sphere and the GazeRayWorld Direction world co-ordinates being 25cm to the left, 6cm up and 1meter relative to the camera position i.e. (0.24876200, 0.05519217, 0.96699090)